# Httpclient calls

Tags: caching, httpclient

I was wondering if there is a way to find out if an ip address or dns was called from an application via api calls.

Let's take this example: You open an app that makes an api call to a specific dns or link etc, you then close the app. If I already know the specified url, where should I look for it in windows? I was thinking there is some sort of cache or something that remains in your pc till you close it, tried to googling couple things but not found the right one yet.

Comment: This is a very broad question - Are you talking about a way to find out for *any* application running on your OS? Try using [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: No, the app should not be running. I am looking for a way to find out if a specified url/link (api-related) was accesed on a computer from an app that is now closed.